# what's the difference between 'allow for ~ to inf.' and 'allow ~ to inf.'?

Tags: usage

What's the difference between ***allow for ~ to do something*** and ***allow ~ to do something***?

I referred to dictionaries, but I couldn't find the answer.

> When we are emotionally charged, we often use anger to hide our more
> primary and deeper emotions, such as sadness and fear, which doesn’t
> ***allow for*** true resolution ***to occur***. Separating yourself from an
> emotionally upsetting situation gives you the space you need to better
> understand what you are truly feeling so you can more clearly
> articulate your emotions in a logical and less emotional way. A
> time-out also helps spare innocent bystanders. When confronted with
> situations that don’t allow us to deal with our emotions or that cause
> us to suppress them, we may transfer those feelings to other people or
> situations at a later point.

[52 Small Changes for the Mind: Improve Memory * Minimize Stress](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=VsoxCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=there.%20When%20you%20take%20the%20appropriate%20time%20to%20digest%20and%20analyze%20your%20feelings,%20you%20can%20mitigate%20hurting%20or%20upsetting%20other%20people%20who%20have%20nothing%20to%20do%20with%20the%20situation.&source=bl&ots=J3JM9leffX&sig=ACfU3U2XtqfqmANMcXrICUzUs6tRRNFpJA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi69_2Y-unyAhVF1GEKHRiVCL8Q6AF6BQjoARAD#v=onepage&q=there.%20When%20you%20take%20the%20appropriate%20time%20to%20digest%20and%20analyze%20your%20feelings%2C%20you%20can%20mitigate%20hurting%20or%20upsetting%20other%20people%20who%20have%20nothing%20to%20do%20with%20the%20situation.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

We allow people/employees/ (direct object) to do something.

We **allow for** in the sense of making allowance for; that's to say, to bear something in mind when planning or carrying out an action.

**Don't completely pack the car, we have to allow for (*leave room for*) mum's suitcase.**

**Her flight is due at five but we have to allow for delays.**

**The job usually takes a day but you should allow for the trainees' inexperience**.

**